# Mapbox - draw lines for each property

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I use mapbox-gl to draw a map. In one of the routes (it's a single line) I have 2 attached properties:

```
{
  id: 17,
  pcs_mode: 'AtRisk'
},
  id: 18,
  pcs_mode: 'Excellent'
}
```

I want to draw 2 lines (each line for a property) and fill using a proper color, depending on `pcs_mode`.

I've tried to draw these like this:

```
const layerId = `segment-condition`;
map.current.addLayer({
  id: layerId,
  type: 'line',
  source: SOURCE_NAME,
  'source-layer': SOURCE_LAYER_NAME,
  layout: {
    'line-join': 'round',
    'line-cap': 'butt'
  },
  paint: {
    'line-color': [
      'case',

      ['==', ConditionStates.Excellent, ['get', 'pcs_mode']],
      CONDITION_COLORS[ConditionStates.Excellent],

      ['==', ConditionStates.AtRisk, ['get', 'pcs_mode']],
      CONDITION_COLORS[ConditionStates.AtRisk],

      ['==', ConditionStates.Distressed, ['get', 'pcs_mode']],
      CONDITION_COLORS[ConditionStates.Distressed],

      ['==', ConditionStates.NoMsl, ['get', 'pcs_mode']],
      CONDITION_COLORS[ConditionStates.NoMsl],

      '#000'
    ],
    'line-width': 5,
    'line-offset': 5
  }
});
```

But it draws only one line (for the first property I suppose). How to draw lines for each property? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have added only one line layer and the conditions are given for line-color. If you want to visualize two lines , then apply separate line-offset values for each condition state (using expression).

Comment: This information can be provided under the comments section